# Need El Capitan installer. Any Apple official link won't work. Need alternatives

Tags: macos

I have a mid 2012 MBP. Came with Mountain Lion, upgraded to Mavericks in 2013 and never touched the OS X again. Long story short: I need El Capitan to run some work apps and it can't be newer because an essential piece of hardware won't work on Sierra or later. I installed High Sierra yesterday to confirm and because I didn't install El Capitan at the time, I can't do it now that Sierra/High Sierra are out. Is there a safe source here to download the installer (torrent)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here you are trying to downgrade from High Sierra to El Capitan and your question is mark as a duplicate of a question regarding upgrading from Yosemite to El Capitan. This makes no sense to me.

Comment: Though this isn't quite a dupe, there are several questions along the same lines. Basically they all boil down to "if your Mac will run something newer than El Cap, you cannot get El Cap from Apple". See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos

Answer (score 0):

If you visit https://itunes.apple.com/app/os-x-el-capitan/id1147835434?mt=12 on a newer macOS version, you should be able to download it via the App Store.

Source: [MacPaw: Download old macOS versions](https://macpaw.com/how-to/download-old-macos-versions)

Comment: Apple won't let me download El Capitan now that High Sierra is out. Mainly because I never had El Capitan before, only Mavericks.

Comment: @VitorKrohne You *should* be able to download El Capitan with this link even if you haven't bought/downloaded it before. What happens if you click on the link (should open the Store App through Safari)? Isn't there a "Download/Get" button in the Store afterwards?

Comment: That version is no good unless you have a machine that won't run on anything newer - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos for a fuller explanation.